# Convergence of HITS Algorithm in the absence of Normalization

Tags: reference-request, matrices, ni.networking-internet

Kleinberg's HITS Algorithm ([Authoritative sources in a hyperlinked environment](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/auth.pdf)) requires the hub (/authority) vector to be normalized after each step of the iteration $x(k+1) = A.x(k)$, in order to guarantee convergence of the algorithm. However, as the matrix is reducible, uniqueness is not guaranteed.

I'm primarily interested in knowing what would happen to the vector if it is not normalized after each iteration. Is it possible to guarantee convergence (even if not uniqueness) under some special cases when the vector is not normalized. For instance, when $\parallel A \parallel_{\infty} \leq 1$ or when $A$ represents the adjacency matrix of a graph.